# Is there an equivalent method to sp_generateinserts for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2005, there was a stored procedure available called **sp_generateinserts**. However in SQL Server 2008, it doesn't seem to exist. Does anyone know if it is still around? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That wasn't a built in system procedure (I don't have it on my SQL2005 installation)

Maybe you downloaded it from somewhere [like here](http://zapdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/07/stored-generate-insert-statements-for.html).

**Edit:** I think this is the original source. http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt

Comment: And no info in Books Online.  I don't think this is part of the database engine...